# Parse PHP array stored as string and concatenate items to string in Power Query

Tags: php, excel, powerquery

I'm doing my first steps with Power Query in Excel. I have exported some data from PHP to a .csv file and want to import them to an excel sheet. This works great with strings and numbers, but I need an improved Power Query statement to read array data.

The PHP string array looks something like:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Text";i:1;s:2:"in";i:2;s:5:"array";}
```

- `"a"` stands for the array name
- `"3"` is the number of items in array
- Within the curly brace `{}` stands the array with
- `"i"` for the index and
- `"s"` for the length of the item (string)
- The strings `"Text"`, `"in"` and `"array"` are the items in the array, which I want to parse.

My Idea is to parse the PHP array string to a Power Query list and concatenate the items to a comma separated string.

In the end i want to have this string:

```
"Text, in, array"
```

I have tried to remove the `a`, `i`, `s`, `;` and the numbers to get something like a json string:

```
= Text.Remove([PHP-array],{"0".."9"}),...
```

And then parse with:

```
Json.Document([JSON-string])
```

But this seems inelegant and prone to error.

Is there a way to parse the PHP array to a list and than serialize it to a comma separated string?

**Edit/Update**

A new idea is to extract only the strings between quotes `"` and merge them. It tried it this way:

```
Table.TransformColumns(#"Column", {{"function", each Text.BetweenDelimiters(_, """", """"), type text}})
```

But this works only for the first occurence. I would need to repeat it for each item and separate them with comma. But how to do this? Is there a kind of a loop in Power Query?

Comment: Please note that PHP serialisation format can contain binary data. If you already have a JSON decoder, why not use JSON in the first place?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: The string of the PHP-array (`a:3:{i:0;s:4_"Text"...`) is given and cannot be changed. The JSON decoder does not parse this string directly. But the structure is quite similar to a JSON. So my idea is to first "trim" the string to get something like a JSON string.

Comment: what is the source of the string? very odd way to store data

Comment: @Erik: A PHP array is stored in an SQL database and exported as .csv.  This is not that unusual, isn't it?

Comment: the example string you show above? yea very strange. why ignore the power and functionality of a database engine and invent your own?

Comment: @Erik: Yes, I know. But this is given. I get the csv as it is and cannot change it. And I have to import it to Excel.  I could do it with VBA, but I want to try it with Power Query, since this is very handy to import data.

Comment: you get that string in a csv file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236597/discussion-between-roland-and-erik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerQuery, this works to convert the data from Column1 of Table1 into a new column called Custom

Splits into a list based on "

If the array item contains a ; then convert that to a null

remove all nulls

Recombine remaining list items separated by , (space)

[image]

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Text.Split([Column1], """"), each if not(Text.Contains(_,";")) then _ else null)),", "))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Wow,! Thanks, this works. At least as long as there is no semicolon `;` and quote `"` within the strings.